# Manually specify cut points or bins for plotting with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

In base R, I can create custom bins using `cut`.
For example, I can create these bins for plotting:

```
data.frame(x = c(5, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3)) %>% mutate(bin = cut(x, breaks = c(0,3,5)))

  x   bin
1 5 (3,5]
2 1 (0,3]
3 3 (0,3]
4 2 (0,3]
5 2 (0,3]
6 3 (0,3]
```

Is this possible with `ggplot2::cut_width` or `cut_interval`?

I want to manually specify the range of values in each bin.

Comment: Re: "For example, I can create three bins for plotting"  Note that for n breaks, n-1 bins are created.  And you can specify any breaks you want that span the data.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use `cut`?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data.frame(x = c(5, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cut(x, breaks = c(0,3,5)))) + 
  geom_bar() +
  xlab("x")
```

The default x axis label is cumbersome, but it is easy to relabel.

[image]

Comment: I've noticed that it converts some values in my data to NA. zero for example, is real data, but it gets converted to NA even if using breaks = c(0,3,5)

Comment: Inside `cut()`, use `include.lowest = TRUE`: `cut(x, breaks = c(0,3,5), include.lowest = TRUE))`.